# Is this Strelkov?

Tags: russia, ukraine

The ibtimes site claims that the guy in this image is Igor Girkin, also know as 'Strelkov":

[image]

> Igor 'Strelkov ' Girkin (C) pictured in Visegrad in 1992 along with a
>   Russian mercenary and a Bosnian Serb commanderwww.klix.ba

Link to the article:

http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/igor-strelkov-key-mh17-crash-suspect-linked-massacre-3000-bosnian-muslims-1992-1458304

Is there any evidence that this is true?

As of now, searching for "Strelkov" on Google leads to this article, as the first result.

Comment: Girkin is supposedly the guy in the middle?

Comment: (C) should mean center, yes. Do you recognize him in the left or right?

Comment: No, I just didn't understand the question.